# Visual Studio:How to remote debug on RDP over another RDP

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

Im trying to debug my code using Visual studio remote debugger. 
The servers set up currently requires me to remote (RDP) on one IP (A) then subsequently remote (RDP) on another IP (B).

I can remote directly on IP (B) but requires changing my network 
then run VS remote debugger.

this is time consuming as being on a network where i can only RDP to IP (A) and connect to TFS for code changes.

Is there a way to do this? set up anything ? software? to make IP (A) a tunnel for me to debug on IP (B)

Comment: which version of visual studio ?

Comment: i have both 2015 and 2013 installed. and also remote debugger for both 2013 and 2015 in the server

Comment: Hi, did you figure out how to remote debug through multiple RDP hops? Do you mind sharing your preferred approach?